# Print column header next to column entry if condition match

Tags: awk

I am having a large file in the following format where 1st column is the id and then all are samples. I am trying to extract only ids for which only one sample is having value larger than 5 and remaining all have values less than 5. Additionally I also want to print the sample id along-with the sample value for which the value is greater than 5. Whats the best way to proceed it? I can identify all ids which full-fill the condition by following which I came across in the forum; but cannot get what I am expecting.

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if($i+0>5) c++; printf "%-5s%s", $i, (i==NF? OFS c ORS: OFS)}c=0}' input.txt | awk 'NR==1{print $0}; NR>1{if ($NF==1) print $0}
```

Input File

```
id      s1      s2      s3      s4      s5
T1      203     3       0       1       80
T2      70      2       0       0       1
T3      50      66      90      321     15
T4      1       4       2       1       10
T5      0       0       0       0       2
T6      2       1       2       11      2
T7      200     3       1       0       0
T8      15      11      9       8       1
T9      1       23      1       2       1
T10     34      1       1       2       1
```

Expected output

```
T2      s1      70
T4      s5      10
T6      s4      11
T7      s1      200
T9      s2      23
T10     s1      34
```

Comment: Post your attempts into the question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks. But I am not a pogromming background. I am an experimental biologist. I hope I am still eligible to ask questions here. I am trying to take help of programming to solve biological question.

Comment: @user3377241: It is not necessary to be a computer scientist here. With your `awk` code you have fulfilled the requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written on mobile couldn't test it should work but.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  for(k=2;k<=NF;k++){
    header[k]=$k
  }
  next
}
{
  for(k=2;k<=NF;k++){
    if($k>5){
      count++ 
      val=$k
      second=header[k]
    }
  }
  if(count==1){
     print $1,second,val
  }
  count=val=second=""
}
' Input_file
```

Comment: I am encountering an error 'fatal: attempt to use array `header' in a scalar context'. It might be because I am use mac. But I am not familiar as I have no programming background. I am a Biologist, so I am sorry if I am missing something here. Thanks

Comment: There were some typos in the answer that I took liberty to fix it myself.